# How to resolve this dilemma when using generics in a simple factory

Tags: java, generics, factory-pattern, design-principles

I have a `Data` class with several sub-class such as `JSONData`, `XMLData`, `IntegerData`. The task is to process different types of incoming data. So based on *program to an interface, not an implementation*, I created the following *interface* with *generic type* for compile-time type checking:

```
interface DataProcessor<T extends Data> {
    void process(T data);
}
```

There are several implemenations based on this interface:

```
* `class JSONDataProcessor implements DataProcessor<JSONData>`
* `class XMLDataProcessor implements DataProcessor<XMLData>`
* `class IntegerDataProcessor implements DataProcessor<IntegerData>`
```

The rest of the work is to make a *simple factory* for creating the corresponding `DataProcessor` instance. So I made the following simple factory, or say it is in fact just a processor mapper as the concrete processor can be cached as *static variables* inside the ProcessorFactory:

```
public class ProcessorFactory {
    public static DataProcessor<?> create() {
          //logic of return an instance
    }
}
```

**The design above has a problem - the `process` method on the returned instance of `DataProcessor` cannot be called directly:**

```
Data data = jsonData;
ProcessorFactory.create().process(data);
```

Question: the code above has a *compilation error* due to the compile-time typing checking as the data has to be the concrete sub-class of `Data`, how to resolve this? Or is the design per se. bad? if so what would be a better design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While design patterns are cool and all, the compilation error you reported in your question, was not caused by the lack of double dispatch.

You get the compilation error because by declaring, for example, this: *`JSONDataProcessor implements DataProcessor<JSONData>{...}`* you've declared this method: *`void process(JSONData data)`*.

You are probably assuming that *`<T extends Data>`* means you can pass an object instance with the static type *`Data`* into *`void process(JSONData data)`* because, after all, *`Data extends Data`*. Except that's not how Java works.

One way to look at the cause of your compilation error is to consider a method declaration like: *`public static void main(String arg){...}`*. Even though *`String extends Object`*, it is illegal to pass a reference with static type *`Object`* into a method declared as *`main(String)`*.

You would get the same compilation error you got with your *`DataProcessor`* if you tried to call that method as *`main(new Object())`*. It would be overkill to correct a mistake that *you* made, by introducing an unnecessary design pattern. In both your case and in the case of *`main(String)`*, the simplest *correction* is to pass in the type that the method is declared to take.

> „*…how to resolve this?…*“

The simplest solution, in my opinion, is to use your methods the way you declared them originally. If yours is implemented in a similar [*way that mine is*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_306909), then I've confirmed that this works…

```
...
JSONData data = new JSONData( ... );
ProcessorFactory.create().process(data);
...
```

This also [*works in my demo*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_306909) (*no design patterns required*)…

```
DataProcessor< Data< ? > > dProc = DataProcessor.Factory.create( );
Data<String> data = new JSONData( ... );
dProc.process( data );
```

> „*…is the design per se. bad?…*“

To call a design „*good*“ or „*bad*“ is subjective. It's more objective to ask yourself: *Is the design **correct**?* Does it correctly do what you *intend* it to do? If it does what you intend it to do, then it's correct. If it doesn't, then back to the <strike>*white*</strike> drawing board.

Another design option you have is to decide not to use Generics at all — *nor design patterns*. Something way simpler might be all you need.

You mentioned: „*program to an interface*“. Maybe all your design needs is plain old subtype polymorphism in the form of old-fashioned interfaces. Generics might not be the best design choice for what you want to do.

Comment: thanks really so much for the answer. I indeed learnt a lot from you answer :) as the first answer is marked as correct, I vote for your answer anyway

Comment: Thanks @Rui! — „*...I indeed learnt a lot from you answer :)*“ — Hey I'm glad it helped you :) — „*...the first answer is marked as correct...*“ — Do you know about: „[*Accepting Answers: How does it work?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/4465539)“? In particular, did you know about the part that says: „*You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time*“? I'm also curious to know how close [*the* _`DataProcessor.Factory.create(Class<P>)`_ *implementation in my demo*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_306909) is to your original design intentions? TIA :)

Comment: I checked yours as the correct answer. But @AvishekBhattacharya 's answer indeed valuable as he mentioned about the single dispatching of Java, which is great

Comment: @Avishek Bhattacharya sorry that i changed the correct answer to deduper, but i indeed appreciate your answer very much also

Comment: Thank you @Rui! I love design patterns as much as anybody. ***BUT*** if you care about making „*good*“ design choices then you have to resist the potentially fatal allure of [*design pattern overkill*](https://www.bing.com/search?q=overuse+of+design+patterns). Java [*Language Architect, Brian Goetz*](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/amber/pattern-match.html#the-visitor-pattern) warns of the Visitor pattern's „*verbosity, intrusiveness, or restrictions*“. [*Static vs. Dynamic Type*](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61bl/su15/materials/guides/static-dynamic.pdf) is another fun favorite.

Answer (score 0):

This is the classic problem with Java as it doesn't support double dispatching. People have circumvented the problem using visitor pattern. In your case, you can possibly expose a visit function inside the `Data` class that accepts the `DataProcessor` and run the `process` method of it. Essentially, reverse the things.

Something like this

```
interface Data {

  ....
   void visit(DataProcessor processor);
}

Data d = JsonData;
d.visit(jsonDataProcessor processor);
```

And the `visit` function for JsonData looks like

```
void visit(JsonDataProcessor processor) {

    processor.process(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks really so much. This is exactly what I would like to know :) shame on me that I know the visitor pattern, but really did not get the essence :)

Comment: AvishekBhattacharya? @Rui's code „*...has a compilation error due to the compile-time typing checking...*“ — Which was a result of the _`ProcessorFactory.create().process(data)`_ line of code in the question. The specific compilation error would have been: _`incompatible types: Data cannot be converted to capture#1 of ?`_. Your answer to the report of a *compilation error* is: „*...This is the classic problem with Java as it doesn't support double dispatching...*“ — Are you saying Java's lack of double dispatch causes capture conversion-related compilation errors? Can you explain why that is?